# req.session has no method 'touch'?

Tags: node.js, express, session

I'm trying to use express-session with connect-redis to store user sessions.

Currently, after a user logs in, I return  `req.sessionID` and then whenever the user wants to make a request to a secure part of the api, he/she has to provide the session ID. The authentication middleware then goes back into redis and checks to see if the session exists and if so, replace the current session with the one stored in Redis.

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
  var session_id = req.body.session_id;
  if (!session_id){
    res.send(401, {status: 0, message: "Not authorized"});
    return;
  }
  console.log(req);
  sessionStore.get(session_id, function(err, session){
    if(err){
      res.send(401, {status: 0, message: "Not authorized"});
      return;
    }
    req.session = session;
    req.sessionID = req.body.session_id;
    return next();
  });
}
```

But for some reason, this error shows up:

```
/node_modules/express-session/index.js:269
  req.session.touch();
              ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'touch'
```

I can't seem to find anyone else online that has this error because touch() is a built in functionality to express-session.

My express-session version is 1.9.3.

Comment: I've been having the same issue for a few days. I was using an older version of express 3.x, but even after upgrading to 4.x, the problem persists

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was having the same error. It seems that if you're coming from express cookie sessions, it was possible to set `req.session = {/* some arbitrary session object */}`. Obviously, `req.session` has some methods on the instance that express needs.

So, just make sure you're not explicitly overriding `req.session` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do need to override the current session but I'll find another way to do it.

Comment: You'll just need to override the properties on session that make sense: `req.session.user = {/* ... */}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
req.session.user = { 'id': 123 }; 
req.session.pageviews = 1; // This too
```

Font: https://davidburgos.blog/expressjs-session-error-req-session-touch-not-function/